# docker-compose module not found even tho it works directly from container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, babeljs

I'm using docker compose to run nodejs and mongo containers. I'm getting `Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-typescript'` when I'm running the node container from docker-compose, however if I run the image directly with docker, it works like a charm. any ideas?

I'm quite new to docker btw, so if you spot any "non best practices" do point them out as well.

```
// docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  api-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/code
      - /home/node/code/node_modules
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: mongodb://db:27017
  db:
    image: mongo:3

// Dockerfile
FROM node:latest

RUN yarn global add nodemon

USER node

RUN mkdir /home/node/code

WORKDIR /home/node/code

COPY --chown=node:node yarn.lock package.json ./

RUN yarn

COPY --chown=node:node . .

CMD ["nodemon", "--exec", "babel-node", "server/index.js"]

// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "inline-dotenv"
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `volumes:` block causes everything your Dockerfile does in `/home/node/code` to be ignored, and then mounts an arbitrarily old copy of the `node_modules` tree over it.  If you've changed the `package.json` file this will be ignored.  I'd recommend deleting these `volumes:` (and the obsolete `links:` directive too).

Comment: if I remove `volumes` nodemon and hot reloading no longer work. about links, without it how can I specify the order of operations? the api server needs the DB to be up

Comment: without `volumes` nodemon isn't working and hot reloading in react isn't working. about `links`, how else can I specify dependencies / order of execution?